# Cant use uuid4 in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i am trying to use uuidv4 its show a error

first iam install uuid using this command `npm i uuidv4`
after i am import {v4} from 'uuid'; to app.js

This is my error

```
TypeError: (0,_uuid.uuid) is not a function. (in'(0,_uuid.uuid)()','(0,_uuid.uuid)' is undefined)
```

this is my code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import Header from './components/Header';
import {uuid} from 'uuid';

const App = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
      id: uuid(),
      text: 'Milk',
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header />
      <FlatList
        data={items}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.text}</Text>}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
export default App;
```

Comment: you are doing `import {uuid} from 'uuid';`

Answer (score 13):

You have to use [`uuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package and [`react-native-get-random-values`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-random-values) before the `uuid` import. [`uuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package has a V4 implementation.

Check the documentation under [UUID > React Native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid#react-native):

> ### [React Native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid#react-native)
>
> 1. Install [`react-native-get-random-values`](https://github.com/LinusU/react-native-get-random-values#readme)
> 2. Import it before `uuid`:
>
> ```
> import 'react-native-get-random-values';
> import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
> ```

Comment: fwiw, if using Expo: `Error: Expo managed workflow support for react-native-get-random-values is only available in SDK 39 and higher.`

Answer (score -2):

Use `import {uuid} from 'uuidv4'`. The mistake is in your import;